# TFS Service - Can it be used with Eclipse AND Git

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, tfs

Recently I tried out the new TFS-Service, and really liked the built in Scrum template for project management, and the new ability to create a team project managed with Git.
It would seem that the Git integration is only possible when using Visual Studio on windows though. Using Eclipse (with the Team Explorer plugin) I was unable to work with a git-based team project.
Is this really the case?

Heres what I've tried:

1. In TFS Service, I have a git-based team project with some commits in it.
   In Eclipse, I connected to the team project, but it seems I can't pull or even see the source in any way. Source control explorer doesn't show any code (or any paths even).
2. In TFS, I created a new git-based team project. In Eclipse I created a new project and used `Team -> Share...` to try and get the code into TFS. But selecting TFS there doesn't seem to have the disired effect: it doesn't understand that it's a git-based team project, and so it doesn't try to push the code with git, but upload it to a new path (`$/some/path/here/`).

So is that it, or perhaps there's a workaround? Maybe I did something wrong?

BTW - I know about using TFS with git-tf, and I'm OK with that option, but it's not what I'm asking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're working on improving this for the next major version of Team Explorer Everywhere (TEE), but this is what you'll want to do today.

Eclipse already has a full featured Git version control provider in the eGit plugin.  This is installed in many versions of Eclipse but if you do not have it you can install it from here:

- http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/1336

To use eGit today against the hosted service you *must* enable alternate credentials in TFS (click on your name in the top right corner, My Profile, Credentials then enable and configure your credentials).

Once this is enabled you can point eGit at your service account repo and you are good to go. In the Import or Share wizards pick Git and then follow through th eGit dialogs.

When you make a commit, if you add #123 into the work item comment it will associate the commit with that work item number when you push it to the server.

Now, I mentioned that we are trying to make this better. What we are aiming to do is show you both your TFVC and your Git related projects when you import and share and if you have picked a Git repo then we'll help you get your credentials set up, clone it and get the version control parts of Eclipse hooked up to eGit (assuming you have eGit installed).  We'll also make sure that the other Team Explorer Views (such as work items, builds etc) all work great and that links to Git commits etc do the right thing. Hope that makes sense - but if anyone wants to talk more about  how Git projects will work in future versions of Team Explorer Everywhere then feel free to drop me a mail (martinwo@microsoft.com)

Comment: If I use eGit with Eclipse and simply point it to the repo on TFS, will I be able to associate commits to Work Items, when I push my work? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer above, simply add #456 into your commit comment to associate that commit with work item 456 when you push the changes to the server.

Comment: Awesome, I tried it just now and it worked. Are there any other TFS commands that could be appended to the commit message? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: The work item thing is the only one we look for right now.  Probably the best place to go for tips right now is the Git tag on the Visual Studio ALM Team Blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/tags/git/)